# Spring Tool Suite application context xml errors even though all beans seem to work as they should

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm configuring jpa and jpa repositories inside one of spring app context xmls.

If I have both  `<jpa:repositories base-package="..." />` and `<context:component-scan base-package="..." />` then Spring Tool Suite shows an error on line 1 saying

`Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in 
 the Problems View and select "Show Details..."`

and upon clicking show details i get this:

```
The errors below were detected when validating the file "spring-context-4.0.xsd" viathe file "app-config.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "spring-context-4.0.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when spring-context-4.0.xsd is validated in the context of app-config.xml.

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,propertyPlaceholder'.  line 22

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,property-placeholder'.  line 91

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,property-override'.  line 155

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,annotation.config'.  line 174

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,component-scan'.  line 194

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,load-time-weaver'.  line 315

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,spring-configured'.  line 392

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,mbean-export'.  line 405

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,mbean-server'.  line 458

sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context,filterType'.  line 488
```

And beside `<jpa:repositories base-package="..." />` there's a warning saying `Referenced bean 'jpaMapppingContext' not found`

Running the application it seems to be working correctly. I can connect to the db and using JpaRepository interface I'm able to fetch data from the db, so I'm unsure why am I presented with a fatal error in STS. I'm assuming that since both jpa:repositories and context:component-scan scan packages that there is some duplication/conflicts when both are used but I'm unsure on how should I approach to fixing it (I could probably split services into their own config xml and either import it in app config or add it to context list in web.xml)

Here is the app-config.xml in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST"
    p:username="sa"
    p:password="" />

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
    p:showSql="true" />

    <util:map id="jpaProperties">
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="test" />
    </util:map>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:packagesToScan="hr.mrplow.test.model"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    p:jpaProperties-ref="jpaProperties" />  

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
    p:rollbackOnCommitFailure="true" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />       

    <jpa:repositories base-package="hr.mrplow.test.DAO" />

    <!-- Services -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="hr.mrplow.test.service" />
</beans>
```

Here's the full app-config.xml

Comment: I believe you are including the same component twice. Can you make sure you are including them once at maximum?

Comment: Hm, well I'm doing a package scan on two different packages and there are no duplicate classes in either.
In DAO package I have a JpaRepository interface and in service package I have a service interface and implementation which has the dao autowired.

Comment: The message suggest an error in `spring-context-4.0.xsd` and duplicate line numbers go up to 488 which is much higher than your file length. What version of spring-framework and of spring-jpa are you using exactly ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta 4.0.5.RELEASE for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in STS:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-160

Though this issue was claimed to be closed, you can see in [this forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/113114-xml-validation-problems-a-schema-cannot-contain-two-global-components-with-the-same) that it still pops up.

You should consider opening a jira ticket with Spring with your case.

Comment: So for the time being, should I ignore the errors? Can I consider them harmless? The application does work but I'm not usually happy with having errors in my applications. Currently my "workaround" is to separate repository and service package scanners into two .xml files and import them in my app-config.xml. This gets rid of the errors

Comment: @MrPlow I know its annoying to see the red flag lurking around the corner. But as long as the application is working it should be fine. You can try one more thing as to remove the version of xsd like http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd and see.

Comment: I'll put up a ticket and I'll play around with it but as far as this thread goes I consider my question answered. Thank you.